# clear state and update with newdata while navigating to next page with pagination in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a table with pages, while moving to each page I will get some Ids. I am trying to fetch current page ids.  When I select the dropdown 'Select All' i am able to get current page ids but while navigating to the next page still state holding the previous page is not updating but whereas **dataIds** having new page ids.

```
const dataIds = data.map((a) => a.id);
useEffect(() => {
    if (dropDown === 'Select All') {
        setCheckedItems([...dataIds]);
    }
}, []);
```

Comment: Can you please share how you've defined your other states and params like dropdown, and data?

Answer (score 0):

If the checkedItems state doesn't get updated it means that the code inside the useEffect is not executed and this means that the content of the useEffect dependency array which they are selectInfoDropDown and pagination haven't changed. So, there might be a problem with updating these two parameters and since you haven't share other parts of the code, it is hard to say what is happening exactly. One thing I can say to include dataIds in the dependency Array of useEffect to update the checkedItems state. So, your code would be something as below:

```
const dataIds = data.map((a) => a.id);
useEffect(() => {
    if (dropDown === 'Select All') {
        setCheckedItems([...dataIds]);
    }
}, [selectInfoDropDown, pagination, dataIds]);
console.log('checkedItems--', checkedItems);
```

Comment: yes, correct checkedItems not getting updated even though dataIds getting updated.

Comment: I've edited my answer. You can check it out.